# Integrating Pandas df as constraint in pulp/pyomo

Tags: python, pandas, constraints, pyomo, pulp

I am working on cost minimization allocation problem, The problem is in implementing constraints i.e. integrating pandas df as constraint..and have shown pseudo code...

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

data_part = [
    {'Part': 'A', 'Units': 20, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger':  True, 'Restricted': True},
    {'Part': 'B', 'Units': 15, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'C', 'Units': 15, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'D', 'Units': 40, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'E', 'Units': 25, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'F', 'Units': 20, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger': False, 'Restricted': True},
]

df_part = pd.DataFrame(data_part)

data_system = [
    {'System': 'Rapidx', 'Type': 'Engine Super', 'Condition': 'Restricted'},
    {'System': 'Assex', 'Type': 'Engine', 'Condition': ''},
    {'System': 'Dulingo', 'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Condition': ''},
    {'System': 'Das', 'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Condition': ''},
]

df_system = pd.DataFrame(data_system)

allocate = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("allocate", [(p, s) for p in df_part.Part for s in df_system.System], cat = 'Binary')

#pseudo code piece will be 

for idx in df_system.System:
    for p in df_part.Part:
        if (system type matches with data_part (w flag TRUE) and restriction condition matches i.e. restricted part will go only to restricted system):
            allocate[part, idx] <= 1
    
        else:
            allocate[part, idx] == 0
```

Output is like:

```
allocate['B', 'Rapidx'] + allocate['C', 'Rapidx'] + allocate['D', 'Rapidx'] + allocate['E', 'Rapidx']   <= 0
allocate['A', 'Assex'] + allocate['B', 'Assex']+ allocate['C', 'Assex'] + allocate['D', 'Assex'] + allocate['F', 'Assex']  <= 0
allocate['A', 'Dulingo'] + allocate['F', 'Dulingo']  <= 0
allocate['A', 'Das'] + allocate['F', 'Das']  <= 0
```

How can this be done programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to do this in pandas. I offer here a pure python way to do what I think you're looking for. The `allowed` variable can be built by merging the two dataframes and filtering but I think the main problem is the structure of your original tables/ lists is not well suited for pandas or even for this kind of filtering. If you have the pandas dataframes you can always do `data_part = df_part.to_dict(orient='rows')`

```py
import pulp

data_part = [
    {'Part': 'A', 'Units': 20, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger':  True, 'Restricted': True},
    {'Part': 'B', 'Units': 15, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'C', 'Units': 15, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'D', 'Units': 40, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'E', 'Units': 25, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'F', 'Units': 20, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger': False, 'Restricted': True},
]

data_system = [
    {'System': 'Rapidx', 'Type': 'Engine Super', 'Condition': 'Restricted'},
    {'System': 'Assex', 'Type': 'Engine', 'Condition': ''},
    {'System': 'Dulingo', 'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Condition': ''},
    {'System': 'Das', 'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Condition': ''},
]

all = [(part['Part'], system['System']) for part in data_part for system in data_system]
model = pulp.LpProblem("test")

# this is not very elegant. But it has more to do with the initial format of the data.
allowed = \
    [(part['Part'], system['System']) for part in data_part for system in data_system
     if (part['Engine'] and system['Type'].startswith('Engine') and part['Restricted']==(system['Condition']=='Restricted')) or
     (part['TurboCharger'] and system['Type']=='TurboCharger' and part['Restricted']==(system['Condition']=='Restricted')) or
     (part['Engine'] and system['Type']=='Engine' and part['Restricted']==(system['Condition']=='Restricted'))]
allocate = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("allocate", all, cat = 'Binary')
not_allowed = set(all) - set(allowed)
allowed_dict = {s: [] for p, s in allowed}
for p, s in allowed:
    allowed_dict[s].append((p, s))

# I'm not sure if this was the kind of constraint you were looking for:
for system, tuplist in allowed_dict.items():
    model += pulp.lpSum(allocate[tup] for tup in tuplist) <= 1

# this eliminates variables that are in not_allowed
for tup in not_allowed:
    model += allocate[tup] <= 0
```

If you want to take out the allocate combinations in `not_allowed` and only keep the 'allowed' ones, it's better to just never define only the possible variables in the first place:

```py
allocate = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("allocate", allowed, cat = 'Binary')
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree w/ some of the elements of the other post.  First, I wouldn't invite `pandas` to the party.  It will just add to the confusion.  straight python is just fine.  You should invest a little bit of time to make your input data a little cleaner so that you can index it by part or system by making those the keys in a dictionary and also thinking about how you can compare the items efficiently when you restructure.

I did transform your data a bit with dictionary comprehensions.  By looking at ways to compare parts-systems you have a couple options with the true/false and naming stuff.  I did a mix.  Made sets of types within parts to support the 1-to-many setup from systems-parts in terms of type, and retained the boolean for "Restricted".  There are other options.

Now, once you have the data in an indexed format that lends itself to comparison, you can use some simple logic to make a list of the compatible pairs and use that as the basis of your index in your model.  In that way, only legal pairs are considered and you do not need to build a P x S data structure (24 indices) when only a handful are needed.  This also alleviates the need to make the extra constraints to clamp illegal pairs to zero as they aren't in the model.

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

data_p = [
    {'Part': 'A', 'Units': 20, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger':  True, 'Restricted': True},
    {'Part': 'B', 'Units': 15, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'C', 'Units': 15, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'D', 'Units': 40, 'Engine': False, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'E', 'Units': 25, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger': True, 'Restricted': False},
    {'Part': 'F', 'Units': 20, 'Engine': True, 'TurboCharger': False, 'Restricted': True},
]

for part in data_p:
    types = set()  # empty set to contain compatible systems
    if part['Engine']:
        types.add('Engine')
    if part['TurboCharger']:
        types.add('TurboCharger')
    part['Types'] = types

part_data = { t['Part'] : { 'Units': t['Units'], 
                            'Types': t['Types'],
                            'Restricted': t['Restricted']} for t in data_p}
for p in part_data:
    print(p, part_data[p])

data_s = [
    {'System': 'Rapidx', 'Type': 'Engine Super', 'Condition': 'Restricted'},
    {'System': 'Assex', 'Type': 'Engine', 'Condition': ''},
    {'System': 'Dulingo', 'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Condition': ''},
    {'System': 'Das', 'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Condition': ''},
]

system_data = {t['System'] :    {   'Type': t['Type'].split(' ')[0], 
                                    'Restricted': t['Condition']=='Restricted'} for t in data_s}

for s in system_data:
    print(s, system_data[s])

# make a set of legal pairings, which will be a sparse index set
legal_pairs = { (p, s) for p in part_data for s in system_data if
                system_data[s]['Type'] in part_data[p]['Types'] and
                system_data[s]['Restricted'] == part_data[p]['Restricted']}

for pair in sorted(legal_pairs, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(pair)

# start setting up the model, using 'legal_pairs' as the basis for your decision variable
allocate = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("allocate", legal_pairs, cat = 'Binary')
```

#### Output:

```
A {'Units': 20, 'Types': {'Engine', 'TurboCharger'}, 'Restricted': True}
B {'Units': 15, 'Types': {'TurboCharger'}, 'Restricted': False}
C {'Units': 15, 'Types': {'TurboCharger'}, 'Restricted': False}
D {'Units': 40, 'Types': {'TurboCharger'}, 'Restricted': False}
E {'Units': 25, 'Types': {'Engine', 'TurboCharger'}, 'Restricted': False}
F {'Units': 20, 'Types': {'Engine'}, 'Restricted': True}
Rapidx {'Type': 'Engine', 'Restricted': True}
Assex {'Type': 'Engine', 'Restricted': False}
Dulingo {'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Restricted': False}
Das {'Type': 'TurboCharger', 'Restricted': False}
('E', 'Assex')
('D', 'Das')
('B', 'Das')
('E', 'Das')
('C', 'Das')
('C', 'Dulingo')
('D', 'Dulingo')
('B', 'Dulingo')
('E', 'Dulingo')
('F', 'Rapidx')
('A', 'Rapidx')
```